# In Java, how to get strings of days of week (Sun, Mon, ..., Sat) with system's default Locale (language)

Tags: java, android, calendar, jodatime, dayofweek

The simplest way:

```
String[] namesOfDays = new String[7] {
    "SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"
};
```

This method does not use Locale. Therefore, if the system's language is not English, this method does not work properly.

Using Joda time, we can do like this:

```
String[] namesOfDays = new String[7];
LocalDate now = new LocalDate();

for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
    /* DateTimeConstants.MONDAY = 1, TUESDAY = 2, ..., SUNDAY = 7 */
    namesOfDays[i] = now.withDayOfWeek((DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY + i - 1) % 7 + 1)
        .dayOfWeek().getAsShortText();
}
```

However, this method uses today's date and calendar calculations, which are useless for the final purpose. Also, it is a little complicated.

Is there an easy way to get Strings like `"Sun"`, `"Mon"`, ..., `"Sat"` with system's default locale?

Comment: On a related note: [*Get date of first day of week based on LocalDate.now() in Java 8*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28450720/642706)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If I have not misunderstood you

```
 calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.US);
```

is what you are looking for. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getDisplayName(int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale)) you can find the documentation,

Or you can also use, [getShortWeekdays()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getShortWeekdays())

```
String[] namesOfDays = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getShortWeekdays()
```

Comment: Is there any static method? Calendar.getDisplayName also needs an instance.

Comment: I found an answer myself. String[] namesOfDays = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getShortWeekdays(); will get the string array.

Comment: If you need to specify a locale, you can use `DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale).getShortWeekdays()`.

Comment: FYI, these date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 11):

```
Date now = new Date();
// EEE gives short day names, EEEE would be full length.
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.US); 
String asWeek = dateFormat.format(now);
```

You can create the date with your desired date and time. And achieve what you want.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getDisplayName( 
    TextStyle.SHORT , 
    Locale.getDefault() 
)
```

## java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of java.time is back-ported to Android (see below).

### `DayOfWeek`

The `DayOfWeek` enum defines seven objects, one for each day-of-week. The class offers several handy methods including `getDisplayName` to generate a string with localized day name.

To localize, specify:

- [`TextStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
String output = DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

You can use the JVM’s current default time zone rather than specify one. But keep in mind the risk: The default zone can be changed at any moment *during execution* by any code in any thread of any app running within the JVM.

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault() ;
String output = DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT , locale );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Without 1.8, you can use [`DateFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) (which also works with Android).

[`DateFormatSymbols.getWeekdays()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getWeekdays())

> Returns: the weekday strings. Use Calendar.SUNDAY, Calendar.MONDAY,
>   etc. to index the result array.

Answer (score 0):

I think my code is useful. You can change it for your purpose easily.

Result string array is "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu" and "Fri".

```
    public String[] getNameOfDays(){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf_day_of_week = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.getDefault());
        String[] nameOfDays = new String[7];

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
            nameOfDays[i] = sdf_day_of_week.format(calendar.getTime());
        }

        return nameOfDays;
    }
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: @OleV.V. Oh. I didn't know that `SimpleDateFormat` and other old date time classes are troublesome. Thank you for let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class daysOfWeek {

     public static String days(String s, int k) {
         String[] days = new String[] {"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"};
         int len = days.length;
         int index = 0;
         int result = 0;
         for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
             if(days[i]==s) {
                index =i;
                k%=7;
                result = (index +k)%7;
             }
            
         }
         return days[result];
     }
     
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         String S ="Tue"; int k =25;
         String s =days(S,k);
         System.out.println(s);
     }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Please try this

```
public static String[] namesOfDays =  {"SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"};


 int day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

System.out.println("Day := "+namesOfDays[day-1]);
```

Comment: I think he wants the days localized.