# Java Calendar doesn't get correct day of the week

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on app which needs to works with dates, hours and such. I got stuck on a pretty simple problem: getting the right day of the week from a given date (in milliseconds).
I know for **sure** that the given time in milliseconds for the current date is the right one, the problem is with the date the `_calendar` variable returns is one day after the one given.

I've tried using DateFormat or other date processing classes from Java, but my current min API for the android app is 22.

```
private void getDayOfTheWeek(Long dateInMillis) {
    Date _date = new Date();
    _date.setTime(dateInMillis);
    Calendar _calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    _calendar.setTime(_date);
    mDayOfTheWeek = mDaysOfTheWeek[_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1];
    Log.d("FirebaseDay", mDayOfTheWeek + "; " + _calendar.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

For example, for the date:
**1564088400000**
It should return: 5, which is Friday, although the logged value for
`_calendar.getTimeInMillis()` is the same as the given one

**Edit:** The problem is not that it returns a number, I have an array of strings, `mDaysOfTheWeek` which gets me the day after the integer received from `_calendar`. 6 is the result given back.

```
private final String[] mDaysOfTheWeek
        = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
```

Comment: FYI, you can use backticks ( ` ) to format inline code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16541525/4398114 You can use this to get the name of the day directly

Comment: The problem is not that it returns a number, I have an array of strings, `mDaysOfTheWeek` which gets me the day after the integer received from `_calendar`

Comment: @DavidBuzatu What result are you getting? 6? [At least it's supposed to be 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.FRIDAY).

Comment: What does `mDaysOfTheWeek` includes in array?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, yes, 6 is the result given back.

`private final String[] mDaysOfTheWeek = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};`

Comment: Sunday is day 1, saturday is day 7, the others inbetween. There is no day zero. `private final String[] mDaysOfTheWeek = {"NONE", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};`

Comment: Oh... I thought Monday is day 1 (East European here). Thank you for the remark @Joachim Isaksson

Comment: You are of course correct that numbering the days from Sunday is an American design error as long as the international standard says that Monday is the first day of the week (it’s just one of many design problems with the `Calendar` class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at to `Calendar` class

```
/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Sunday.
 */
public final static int SUNDAY = 1;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Monday.
 */
public final static int MONDAY = 2;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Tuesday.
 */
public final static int TUESDAY = 3;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Wednesday.
 */
public final static int WEDNESDAY = 4;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Thursday.
 */
public final static int THURSDAY = 5;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Friday.
 */
public final static int FRIDAY = 6;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Saturday.
 */
public final static int SATURDAY = 7;
```

So, the day of the week for **1564088400000** returns 6(`public final static int FRIDAY = 6;`). 5. indice(6 - 1) of your `mDaysOfTheWeek` is **Saturday**.

Comment: As @Joachim Isaksson pointed out earlier, that was my mistake. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, he was posted while i am typing answer :)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> It should return: 5, which is Friday, …  6 is the result given back.

The terrible `Calendar` class has many problems.

- One problem is its use of shifting behavior implicitly depending on the JVM’s current default locale. When your code runs on a JVM set to United States locale, you will find Thursday to be a different day of the week of Sunday-Saturday, than in Europe or other places where a week is Monday-Sunday.
- Another problem is crazy zero-based counting, 0-6 for days of the week, and 0-11 for months.

Use *java.time* instead. The counting is sane (1-7 for Monday-Sunday), and the time zone behavior can be made predictable and explicit.

**Important:** Time zone is crucial. For more eastern zones, your moment appears as Friday. For more western zones, your moment appears as Thursday.

```
Instant                            // Represent a moment in UTC.
.ofEpochMilli(                     // Parse your count-from-epoch 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
    1_564_088_400_000L             // Use underscores where you like, to make numeric literals more readable.
)                                  // Returns an `Instant` object.
.atZone(                           // Adjust from UTC to some time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" )      // Specify time zone using `Continent/Region` format, never 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `CST` or `IST`. 
)                                  // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.getDayOfWeek()                    // Returns a `DayOfWeek` object.
.getDisplayName(                   // Generate automatically-localized string for the name of the day-of-week.
    TextStyle.FULL ,               // How long or abbreviated.
    Locale.US                      // Locale determines (a) human language for translation, and (b) cultural norms for issues such as abbreviation, punctuation, capitalization.
)                                  // Returns a `String`.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/KaLiXE).

> Friday

If you insist on a number 1-7 for Monday-Sunday, call `getValue` instead of `.getDisplayName`.

```
.getValue()
```

> 5

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

> I am currently working on app which needs to works with dates, hours and such.

Then you should stop using the terrible date-time classes that were obsoleted years ago by the adoption of JSR 310. Use only the modern *java.time* classes. Never use `Date` or `Calendar`.

## Count-from-epoch

> from a given date (in milliseconds).

If you mean a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, then parse as an `Instant`. An `Instant` represents a moment in UTC, a specific point on the timeline.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_564_088_400_000L ) ;
```

See this code run live at IdeOne.com.

> instant.toString(): 2019-07-25T21:00:00Z

## Date

> getting the right day of the week

Determining a date from a moment requires the context of a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone. The date can simultaneously be “tomorrow” in Paris France while “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

To adjust a moment into a time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to your `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

If you want to view the date through the lens of UTC rather than some other time zone, use `OffsetDateTime` class.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC ;  // Constant for UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). 
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( offset ) ;
```

If you want to go this route (UTC), replace `zdt` in code below with this `odt`.

## Day of week

Interrogate for the day-of-week using the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

```
DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

> or example, for the date: 1564088400000 It should return: 5,

No, I suggest you work with smart objects rather than dumb integers. Rather than using `5` to mean `Friday` (which, by the way, would mean `Thursday` in the United States), pass `DayOfWeek` enum objects around your code base.

To report the day-of-week to use, localize.

```
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
```

Or, if you insist, generate a number using the ISO 8601 numbering scheme of 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.

```
int dayOfWeekNumber = dow.getValue() ;
```

> private final String[] mDaysOfTheWeek = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

No need to roll-your-own. Use the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer with so many details I've read about in others topics, but didn't quite get how it works. The only problem I have with this java.time and why I didn't use it, is that android studio prompts that my current minim API is 22, but for `Instant instant = Instant.getTimeInEpoch()' it marks it as error because only from API 26 it can be used

Comment: @DavidBuzatu See the bullets at the end of my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is returning 6, which is Friday, as expected. But your array of strings mDaysOfTheWeek is set wrong.

Reference:

From the Class **Calendar.java**

```
public final static int SUNDAY = 1;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Monday.
 */
public final static int MONDAY = 2;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Tuesday.
 */
public final static int TUESDAY = 3;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Wednesday.
 */
public final static int WEDNESDAY = 4;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Thursday.
 */
public final static int THURSDAY = 5;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Friday.
 */
public final static int FRIDAY = 6;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Saturday.
 */
public final static int SATURDAY = 7;
```